# How to give red color for rows on html table that have different values on same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to give red color for rows on  HTML table that have different values on the same row ?**

I need  when at least one cell from row  different from each other

then give red font to full row

if you see below the row that has the same value on all cells not changed color.

I need function give red color for the row that have at least one value different from others on the same row

so How to make the function do that by jquery or javascript  do red color for a row if it has

at least different cell values.

[image: rows have different values give red rows font]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<tr bgcolor="#6699FF" width="100%">
    <th>Part1</th>
    <th>Part2</th>
    <th>Part3</th>
    <th>Part4</th>
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</table>


<button id="button">Click Me</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by doing simple this way.

- Loop each `tr` then check the text value of each `td`.
- If any text is different from the first text, You can turn on the flag name `isDiff` is true.
- If `isDiff` is true, you can `css` color for the row.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  MakeColorForDifferentContent();
});

function MakeColorForDifferentContent (){
  $("table tr").each((_, tr) => {
    var tempValue = $($(tr).find('td:first-child')).text();
    var tds = $(tr).find('td:not(:first-child)');
    
    var isDiff = false;
    tds.each((_, td) => {
      if($(td).text() !== tempValue){
        isDiff = true;
        return true;
      } 
    });
    
    if(isDiff)
     $(tr).css('color', 'red');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<col width="500">
<tr bgcolor="#6699FF" width="100%">
    <th>Part1</th>
    <th>Part2</th>
    <th>Part3</th>
    <th>Part4</th>
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</table>


<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: thank you for reply this actually function i need but i need to apply function when html loaded no using click event so how to do that

Comment: I've just updated my answer. You should use `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: Are this  will work to any table dynamically or not

Comment: Every time you reload the table content. You should call the function `MakeColorForDifferentContent()` to apply it. Check my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of unique values of *td* from each *tr*. If the length is more than one then the values are not same otherwise same.

**Using JavaScript:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var trList = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  trList.forEach(function(tr){
    var count = [...new Set(Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td')).map(i => i.textContent))].length;
    if(count > 1) tr.style.color = 'red';
  });
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <tr bgcolor="#6699FF" width="100%">
    <th>Part1</th>
    <th>Part2</th>
    <th>Part3</th>
    <th>Part4</th>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

**Using jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var count = [...new Set($(this).find('td').map((_,i) => $(i).text()).get())].length;
    if(count > 1) $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <tr bgcolor="#6699FF" width="100%">
    <th>Part1</th>
    <th>Part2</th>
    <th>Part3</th>
    <th>Part4</th>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```